# Adding space in Dynamic SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

Can some one please to add the space before FROM in Dynamic SOQL.

```
string query ='SELECT ' + qFields +
                       'FROM contact'+
                       ' WHERE user_num__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(uNum) + '\''+
                       ' LIMIT 1';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that

- `qFields` is generated at runtime from the Custom Setting ( a list of fields to query),
- and if `qFields` is a new custom setting for this changeset
- then, depending on your testmethod setup either ..

a) testmethod relies on `seealldata=true` and by definition, PROD has no value or
b) testmethod relies on `seeAllData=false` and your testmethod doesn't mock the custom setting value

Hence PROD will not have a value for `qFields` and the deployment test will fail because `qFields` is null and the select statement generates as:

```
SELECT null FROM contact WHERE user_num__c = 'someunum' limit 1
```

To solve:

1. Mock the custom setting value in the testmethod (best choice) or
2. Deploy the custom setting first in a changeset(0), populate in PROD, then deploy the rest of the changeset(1)

Answer (score 4):

Just use `' From'` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. ' from' will add the space...

```
string qfields = 'stack';
string uNum  = 'exchange';
string query ='SELECT ' + qFields +
                       ' FROM contact'+
                       ' WHERE user_num__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(uNum) + '\''+
                       ' LIMIT 1';

system.debug(query);
```

Comment: Still not help full...FYi..its only complaining  when i validate against production and works fine in Sandbox..ERROR:: System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'FROM'

Comment: Can you post what you are getting in System.debug ...then we can run it outside the apex code and see where the error is !!

Comment: Im getting the error while deploying the changes...ERROR:: System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'FROM'17:06:57.170 Printed query from sandbox..(170233661)|USER_DEBUG|[44]|INFO|query#SELECT TRA_Given__c, Receive_Customer_Feedback_By_Email__c, Receive_Market_Summary_By_Email__c, Evening_Phone_RK_Provided__c, FirstName, Foreign_Resident__c, Gender__c, HomePhone, Investment_Objective__c FROM contact WHERE user_num__c = '22494878' LIMIT 1

Comment: Based on that error, I'd assume qFields is empty

Comment: qfields are also part of the same change set. its a custom setting value.

Comment: Are you able to run the same query as posted as part of debug logs in developer console in Production? Without any error?

Comment: @Nick ..you are right..test class is expecting the custom setting to be available before we deploy the Apex class/test class. Trick is  i created the custom setting first then deployed the code changes and worked. Please post your Comment as Answer.

Comment: @KrForce Then the real answer is to rewrite your tests so they are not reliant on existing data.